# MySQL Syntax Error - where did I go wrong?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm doing this to create a SQL user account, and grant permissions, creation works fine but when I get to grant part, it fails.

Update: Now it doesn't throw an error, but it just doesn't grant permissions, confusing error, syntax is correct, everything.

Code:

```
$query = $this->ci->db->query("GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ".$db_add." TO '".$username."'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;");
```

Comment: You cannot bind database/table information, it isn't allowed.

Comment: If I do insert directly though I run the risk of SQL injection. Bare in mind I've enforced ctype_alnum for the strings to ensure they are not malformed. Only exception is I do a check if it contains _, if so, replace it with air, then ctype_alnum, then continue if it's clean.

Comment: It is OK to bind the user name, you just cannot bind the database name/ table name.

Comment: You only risk injection if you use data that you are not directly in control of. Why would your users be specifying table names? If they are, you just need to sanitise the data properly.

Comment: @HoboSapiens I've enforced ctype_alnum for the strings to ensure they are not malformed. Only exception is I do a check if it contains _, if so, replace it with air, then ctype_alnum, then continue if it's clean.

Comment: @CBMC Then you shouldn't have a problem  with SQL injection.

Comment: So this should work then? $query = $this->db->query('GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON '.$db_add.' TO ?@?;',array($username, "localhost"));

Comment: Upon running the query, it doesn't grant permissions to the specified database still. However, it creates the account.

Comment: Upon more fighting, it just won't grant any permissions to the database specified, code: $query = $this->ci->db->query("GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ".$db_add." TO '".$username."'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;"); - It returns no error, but it doesn't grant permissions on the database I told it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't quote database objects with single quotes, you use backticks or nothing, if your object names are sensible and do not require quoting or escaping.

Also, you need to specify which objects in the database, or `*` for everything.

Also, do not grant `ALL` or `WITH GRANT OPTION` unless you really mean it.

Also, accounts with this much privilege almost certainly shouldn't be automatically created for any reason.

Also, while the following form is syntactically correct...

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `the_database`.* to 'leethaxor'@'localhost';
```

...if you didn't already create the user, then you just granted access to anybody who can guess that username from the specified host, because the password is empty.  The first grant should include something like...

```
... IDENTIFIED BY 'a_password' ...
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html